# Constant Time Operations with Adjacency Lists

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist, graph, adjacency-list

I am implementing a graph in Java using adjacency lists which must use space proportional to Edges + Vertices.  My initial program contains an array of length V, (number of vertices), and each index contains an ArrayList of Edges, showing all the edges connected to each vertex.

Now, I was told that the operation existsEdge(x, y) must run in O(1) time. 
The way I thought about it was to access index x in the array (taking O(1) time) and check if the list at that index has an Edge(x,y).

However, I am unsure of this time complexity.  I know that the length of an  ArrayList at any particular index will never be more than the number of vertices in the graph, but I do not know for sure if this is considered constant time.  Regardless of the amount of data, each list will have length <= V, so traversing has a clear upper bound.

Is this the same as O(1), or is this a different time complexity? If it is different, I am not exactly sure how I could go about using an ArrayList to create this structure.

Comment: Can you share what you have done so far?

Comment: I would normally, but this is part of an assignment.  Essentially, I have an array indexed from 0 to V-1. And for example, if vertex 1 is connected to 0, 3, and 4,... arr[1] contains an ArrayList with the following {Edge(0,1), Edge(1,3), Edge(1,4)}.  If I call existsEdge(1,3), it should return true in constant time. @Yash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is not considered O(1), it's O(V), cause in the worst case a vertex could be connected to all other vertices, and the ArrayList would have length V-1. If you want O(1), you should use a [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) instead of an ArrayList. Also, you don't need an Edge class, you can simply store the connected vertices.

Let's say vertex 1 is connected to 2, 4 and 5, then at position 1 in your array, you would have a HashSet (2, 4, 5). Now if you have to check for existence of edge (1, 4), you would go to index 1 of the array(as you described) and then you would call `array[1].contains(4)`, which is an O(1) operation.

Comment: Thank you- the reason I was storing edges was because they have weights as well, so I felt that storing the edge itself would prevent me from losing the data on the edge weight. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Then use a HashMap instead of a HashSet. Use the vertex as key and the weight as value. Something like array[1] = [(2 -> w12), (4  -> w14), (5 -> w15)]. You can still check existence in O(1) with array[1].containsKey and get edge weight in O(1) with array[1].get.